# Pegar id de um link e criar div em outra página

Tags: javascript

Bom, to tentando pegar id de um link que está mais ou menos assim

**home.php**

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#" id="o-v">Teste</a></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function() {
    const o_v = document.getElementById('o-v');
        o_v.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var video = document.createElement('div');
        video.className="video";
        video.appendChild();
        console.log(video);
        // alert(o_v, video);
    });
});
```

até ai tudo bem, oque eu precissaria era jogar essa div dentro da minha `.box` só que essa `.box` é a `noticia.php`, seria algo mais ou menos assim, como eu recupero a `class video` sendo que ela está em outra página?

**noticia.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const box = document.getElementByClassName('box');
    video.className="video";
    video.appendChild(box);
    console.log(video);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primeiro -** seu código está muito bagunçado, está misturando **`jQuery`** com **`Javascript`**, mas, podemos criar a **div video** dessa maneira:

```js
$(function() {
  const o_v = $('#o-v');
  
  o_v.on('click', function() {
    var video = document.createElement('div');
    video.className = "video";
    video.id = "video";
    console.log(video);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" id="o-v">Teste</a></li>
</ul>
```

Agora para recuperar a **`div video`** na página **noticia.php**, existem diversas formas, uma delas é com o método **[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** do jQuery, que basicamente é um método Ajax:

```
$(function() {
  $('.box').load('home.php #video');
})
```

> Desta maneira você traz somente a div video na página noticias.php.